# PHP Class for HTML tables: strange attribute assignment

Tags: php, class

In a class that builds an HTML table I have this method that renders the table. Everything works fine (indentation, closing tags, data presentation, etc.) except for the HTML attribute assignment under certain conditions. When I set cells data I call `setData()` that receives three parameters and use it like this. Pay attention on how I set the third parameter (cell attributes):

**Method definition:**

```
public function setData(
        array $data,
        array $row_attributes = [],
        array $cell_attributes = []
    ): bool {
    // the code
}
```

**The call:**

```
$table->setData(
    $pagination->resultset,
    [], // row attributes
    array( // cell attributes
        array(), // row 1 (index 0)
        array( // row2 (index 1)
            ["id"=>"R2C1id"], // row 2, cell 1
            ["id"=>"R2C2id", "onclick"=>"R2C2_onclick();"], // row 2, cell 2
        ),
        array( // row 3
            [],
            [],
            ["id"=>"R3C3id", "selected"=>"selected"], // row 3, cell 3
            [],
            [],
            [],
            []
        )
    )
);
```

In this example the table has seven columns.

And here you will see the HTML output. Pay attention to cells attributes on rows two and three:

```
<div class='table-body'>
    <div class='table-row'>
        <div class='table-row-cell'>1</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'>Consumidor Final</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'>Consumidor Final</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'></div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'>1</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'></div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='table-row'>
        <div class='table-row-cell' id='R2C1id'>2</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell' id='R2C2id' onclick='R2C2_onclick();'>Prueba SRL</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell' 0='Array' 1='Array'>Tu Prueba</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell' 0='Array' 1='Array'>12345678901</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell' 0='Array' 1='Array'>1</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell' 0='Array' 1='Array'></div>
        <div class='table-row-cell' 0='Array' 1='Array'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='table-row'>
        <div class='table-row-cell'>3</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'>Otra Prueba SA</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell' id='R3C3id' selected='selected'>Prueba 2</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'>12345678902</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'>1</div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'></div>
        <div class='table-row-cell'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the code I use to get all this done. I will show you the piece of code for cell rendering and the method that processes the attributes.

**The cell rendering:**

```
        // process cells
        $row_counter = 0;
        foreach ($this->data as $data) { // row
            $row_build = "";
            $cell_counter = 0;
            foreach ($data as $cell_data) { // cell
                if ($cell_counter < $col_count) {
                    $row_build .= $this->getHtmlDiv(
                        $html_cell_class,
                        $cell_data ?? "",
                        $this->getHtmlAttributes("cell", $row_counter, $cell_counter),
                        3
                    );
                }
                $cell_counter++;
            }

            // $cell_counter++;

            // complete empty cells to preserve row:hover on full row
            while ($cell_counter < $col_count) {
                $row_build .= $this->getHtmlDiv(
                    $html_cell_class,
                    "",
                    $this->getHtmlAttributes("cell", $row_counter, $cell_counter),
                    3
                );
                $cell_counter++;
            }

            $body_build .= $this->getHtmlDiv(
                $html_row_class,
                $row_build,
                $this->getHtmlAttributes("row", $row_counter, 0),
                2,
                true
            );
            $row_counter++;
        }
```

**The method for attributes:**

```
private function getHtmlAttributes(string $section, int $row, int $column): array
{

    if (count($this->html_attributes[$section]) > 0) {
        if (array_key_exists($row, $this->html_attributes[$section])) {
            if ($section === "cell") {
                if (array_key_exists($column, $this->html_attributes[$section][$row])) {
                    return $this->html_attributes[$section][$row][$column];
                }
            }
            return $this->html_attributes[$section][$row];
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, while I was posting the question and picking the code the answer appeared.In method `getHtmlAttributes()` there was an `else` condition missing.

```
private function getHtmlAttributes(string $section, int $row, int $column): array
{

    if (count($this->html_attributes[$section]) > 0) {
        if (array_key_exists($row, $this->html_attributes[$section])) {
            if ($section === "cell") {
                if (array_key_exists($column, $this->html_attributes[$section][$row])) {
                    return $this->html_attributes[$section][$row][$column];
                } else { // <-- this 
                    return [];
                }
            }
            return $this->html_attributes[$section][$row];
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```